# How can I access two Oracle databases with different versions (8i and 9) using perl?

Tags: perl, oracle, dbi, dbd

I'm currently accessing an Oracle database version 9i (9.2.0.8.0) using perl modules DBI (1.613) and DBD::Oracle (1.26). The current scope of the project now requires that I access a version 8i (8.1.7.4.0 ) Oracle database and, according to the [DBD::Oracle project](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBD-Oracle-1.26/Oracle.pm), I can only access this second database with a DBD::Oracle version 1.20 or below.

I know I could possibly use the DBD version 1.20 to access both databases, but I was wondering if its possible to have installed the two versions of the DBD module and use the acceptable version for each database (less prone to errors).

Comment: do you need to access both databases from the same program simultaneously?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe that the server version has any bearing on the DBD::Oracle version you can use, only the version of the *client libraries* that you install. The 9.2, 10.1, and 10.2 versions of the Oracle client libraries support connecting to Oracle server 8.1.7.4, and the latest version of DBD::Oracle remains compatible with all client libraries from 9.2 up, so I don't think that you will actually have any problem at all. However, if you install the version 11 client, you will lose the ability to connect to server versions below 9.2.0.

Comment: well, that's an understanding. :)

Answer (score 4):

Install the different versions of DBI/DBD::Oracle into two different places, see [`INSTALL_BASE`](http://p3rl.org/ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker#INSTALL_BASE)/[`--install_base`](http://p3rl.org/Module%3a%3aBuild#INSTALL_PATHS). Access them seperately by setting [PERL5LIB](http://p3rl.org/run#PERL5LIB) appropriately.

[local::lib](http://p3rl.org/local%3a%3alib) helps you automate this whole affair.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to access the two database versions from the same program run you can do as follows:

- install both versions in your system using [local::lib](http://p3rl.org/local%3a%3alib)
- run a [DBD::Proxy](http://p3rl.org/DBD%3a%3aProxy) server with `@LIB` configured to load one version of DBD::Oracle
- run your script with `@LIB` configured to load the other version of DBD::Oracle
- in your script connect to one database using DBD::Oracle as usual and to the other one through the proxy.